# Why FindRoot does not give all roots?

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to solve complicated equation and use FindRoot to find roots numerically. I do not understand the following problem. I provide the simple example. Considert the equation:

```
F[x_] := x + x^2 - x^3;
Solve[F[x] == 0, x]

{{x -> 0}, {x -> 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])}, {x -> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])}}
```

Then, I try to solve it numerically, specifying points were I expect roots:

```
Table[FindRoot[F[x] == 0, {x, X}], {X, -0.61, 0.01, +1.6}]

{{x -> -0.618034}}
```

However, I obtain only one root instead of three. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Small syntax error on the `Table` parameters.  Use brackets for successive values.

```
Table[FindRoot[F[x] == 0, {x, X}], {X, {-0.61, 0.01, +1.6}}]
```

Comment: Thx, sorry for silly question.... I really don't see it...

Comment: In docs: `Table[expr, {i, {i1, i2, ...}}] uses successive values i1, i2, ...` .  Your code does not have the inner brackets.

Comment: Also `FindRoot[F[x] == 0, {x, #}] & /@ {-0.61, 0.01, +1.6}`